# python 3.3.5 and pyodbc 2.1.7

Tags: python, linux, bash

I'm a beginner in Python.

I have a linux Redhat 4.4 server.It has python2.6 by default.
I installed pyodbc 2.1.7 and python 3 tried "import pyodbc" in python3. I got the error below.

1)Is there something like pyodbc 2.1.7 is not compatiable with 
python3 ? I checked the documentation for pyodbc, but did not find anything conclusive. rpm was used to install pyodbc.

2) Is pypyodbc a good workaround in this case for working with python3(like anyone has any bad experience)? 
I tried using pypyodbc and basic select and all works with python3 with some workaround.

Python 2.6.6 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2

```
$ import sys

$ import pyodbc

$ exit()
```

Python 3.3.5 (default, Mar 13 2014, 20:11:10)
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)] on linux

```
$ import sys

$ import pyodbc
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_pyodbc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a try with the following and it did the trick

```
virtualenv vtest -- for testing purpose. Do not use it in your case

source vtest/bin/activate -- for testing purpose. Do not use it in your case

pip3 install pyodbc
```

Then execute your `python3`

```
import pyodbc
```

Make sure you are using `pip3`

Comment: @rohti2219 can you please accept my answer if it helps you?

Answer (score 1):

1. There shouldn't be any compatibility issues between Python3 and pyodbc.  That being said, there appears to have been some issues with the odbc binaries in the npm package.  I recommend you install `unixodbc-dev` from npm and `pyodbc` from pip separately.

Comment: 2.  I've used pypyodbc and it is close to a drop-in replacement as it implements the same class interfaces.  However, you will still need driver libs.

Comment: regarding your comment about compatibility, how can we pyodbc - python version compatibility?there is not much  documentation on pyodbc.

Comment: I have used the library with python3.  Their documentation was recently moved to google code, but still states 3.x compatibility.  
https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/